# Gitorious source code isn't routing properly

Tags: gitorious

I have installed gitorious on my local server and when I try to run it
in my browser, I don't see the homepage. Instead I see this page.
http://gitorious.googlegroups.com/web/Screenshot.png?gsc=gBX1HyMAAADO...

Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RTM: http://gitorious.org/gitorious/pages/UbuntuInstallation

You need to create admin user etc. Configure it and it will work fine.